# Binary Search Tree? Algorithm

Tags: search

Does anyone know how to make an algorithm that transforms a binary search tree into an AVL tree, and yes transform it and not make another tree (so it will only be done using rotations) and not with the DSW technique... and in C. The tricky part here is that there is lots of cases since a binary search tree can be unbalanced in various ways and there being 4 types of rotations.

Comment: After doing your homework, should I iron your shirt master?

Comment: Well, since you use C, you can reset the tree, leaving only its root, and re-use it as the result, instead of creating a new pointer to a new tree. A possible solution is to temporarily store all of the values of the tree (using any way you wish), clear the tree, and then add the items using any auto-balancing technique you wish. That's actually like DSW. :)

Comment: @androiddeveloper true

Comment: @BandanaKoper I've now thought of a possible solution, but since I learned this topic a long time ago I might be wrong: you can traverse the tree and use the same exact mechanism of balancing used in any algorithm you choose. question is how best to traverse, and if it really works. You might be able to balance only the needed leaves by checking the level of each of them. I think the easiest way is indeed like DSW...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the DSW technique does everything in-place (no memory allocations) if that's what you're looking for.
Otherwise, can you run the fix-up algorithm from AVL continually until the tree has no more changes? That's a technique used in a lot of algorithms that might apply here.